# "bash" process does not die

Tags: bash, process, kill

A process with name (command) "bash" is taking about 100% CPU power. When I use the `kill` command to kill it I don't get any error messages but it nonetheless doesn't die. It doesn't belong to root. Here is the output of `ps aux` for this process.

```
  16819 69.0  0.0  31788  4544 ?        Rs   15:49 188:45 /bin/bash
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `/proc/16819/wchan`, and `/proc/16819/syscall`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, `kill` only sends `SIGTERM`, which asks the process to quit rather than forcing it to quit. Send `SIGKILL` (signal number 9), which forces it to quit, with the following:

```
kill -9 16819
```

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
sudo kill -9 16819
```

Note that `kill -9` should only be used if closing the application normally fails, as it doesn't give the application any time to clean up after itself, to finish up changing anything on disk (potentially leaving a corrupt file), or to save anything.

Comment: Why would you suggest `SIGKILL` blindly?

Comment: I didn't. The last paragraph makes the downsides clear.